# Purelayout - Center icon to dynamic two labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, center, pure-layout

I have added an arrow icon in following sample: https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout

```
[self.nextarrow autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTrailing withInset:kLabelHorizontalInsets];
[self.nextarrow autoAlignAxis:ALAxisHorizontal toSameAxisOfView:self.bodyLabel];
```

This will center to multiple line body label. But I would like my icon to center single line label and multiple line bodyLabel.